# Create Generic Module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generics

I'm a newbie to rails. I have created a reports module for a particular project. Now, we want to make it generic across all project like a reports gem. My question is not about how to create & use gem. My questions is "how to make a generic reports lib". For eg. I have a helper module in reports,

```
module Libquery
 module Helper
  include QueryConstants(which is dynamic - based on the project) 
    #methods
   end
 end
```

end

My approach: each project will include LibQuery::Helper and also it will include its own constants file.

```
module ProjectX
 module Query 
  module Helper
   include Libquery::Helper
   #nothing - inherit all helper methods in libquery
   end
 end
end
```

But I'm wondering if that's the most elegant way of doing things ? Or any better way to do it?

Comment: respect conventions: modules and classes must be capitalized

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all modules must be capitalized:

```
module MyModuleName
```

Second, to use a `lib` it's best to include it in `autoload_paths` (in your `application.rb` file) like this

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib/my_shared_libs)
```

This means rails will load it automatically, and you'll have available 'out of the box'.

Third, external modules shouldn't depend on project-based modules and classes, since the whole point is to make them easily reusable.

So it boils down to this:

```
#/lib/my_shared_libs/fun_things.rb

module FunThings
  ... your code
  def laugh
    puts 'haha'
  end
end

#/models/user.rb

class User
  include FunThings
end

User.new.laugh # => 'haha'
```

Comment: Okay . Let me try to ask in other way! I have all common function in a module! the function will work only if it include some constants file. that constants file varies based on every project. Now, what is the best approach to reuse the module?